# How to write a code to do this job?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use following code in VC1 :

```
ResultViewController *primaryView = [[ResultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultView" bundle:nil];
UIImageView *profileView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"profile.png"]];
[_coinView setPrimaryView: primaryView.view];
[_coinView setSecondaryView: profileView];
[_coinView setSpinTime:1.0];
```

than I have following code in a View file:

```
-(IBAction) flipTouched:(id)sender{
    [UIView transitionFromView:(displayingPrimary ? self.primaryView : self.secondaryView)
                            toView:(displayingPrimary ? self.secondaryView : self.primaryView)
                          duration: _spinTime
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft+UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            if (finished) {
                                displayingPrimary = !displayingPrimary;
                             }
         }
    }];
}
```

this code combo helps me to flip a view shown in VC1, it works well, but now what I am trying to do is to have a button shown in VC1, when it clicked, I can also flip the same view. So I guess the functional code should be written in VC1, and I just cannot figure out a good code to do that, anyone can help me please? BTW, how can I call "[self loadData]" of VC1 in view file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[_coinView flipTouched: nil ];
```

I find out this works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to wire up `flipTouched:` to a `UIButton`:

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init]; // Or an outlet from your XIB/storyboard
[myButton addTarget:self
             action:@selector(flipTouched:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Hi, would you excuse my simplicity and give some more details? I tried your code, but it seems not go through compilation: No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'addTarget:selector:forControlEvents:'

Comment: My apologies, I wrote the method incorrectly. It should be `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`, not `addTarget:selector:forControlEvents`. I've edited my answer.